# SQL Help, Group by another table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select
  d.DepartmentId,
  d.Name,
  d.GroupName,
  eph.Rate * 40 * 52 * count(edh.EmployeeId) as AnnualPay
from
  HumanResources.Department d,
  HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory eph,
  HumanResources.Employee e,
  HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory edh
where
  e.CurrentFlag = 'True' and
  edh.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID and
  edh.EmployeeID = eph.EmployeeID and
  e.EmployeeID = eph.EmployeeID
group by
  d.departmentID;
```

The goal is to write a report to display the **departmentid, name, groupname,** the total annual pay for all employees who work in that department and the number of employees who work in that department.

To calculate the `annual pay`, multiply each of the employees’ pay rate by **40 hours for 52 weeks in the year**.

Only include departments that spend more than `half a million dollars` on their total annual pay for all employees.

All employees should be current (use currentflag).

Sort the report by the total annual pay of employees in descending order.

The Tables are included, I can't figure out how to group by each department...[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFTv4.jpg)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I've got quite a few questions about your question. I'll have to separate them over multiple comments. Here's the first one: (1) Are you sure this is MySQL? The database diagram is for AdventureWorks, which is usually a SQL-Server thing. It could be ported to MySQL though, so you may be right. Depending on how complex the answers provided turn out to be, it may not make any odds.

Comment: And the others: (2) I don't know the AdventureWorks data, but from the diagram, there may be employees who aren't paid weekly but your `* 52` seems to assume everyone is paid weekly. (3) Although you are handling employees who have left using the `CurrentFlag`, I think you may also need to handle employees with several entries in EmployeeDepartmentHistory (employees who have moved department or changed shift) and employees with several entries in EmployeePayHistory (those who have had their salary changed).

Comment: If you are concerned about either or both questions (2) and (3), I'd recommend first creating a query which returns the correct current data for each individual employee, making sure you don't have any employee in there twice. Once that's in place, then worry about summing up all the salaries on a per department basis.

Comment: Can an employee belong to more than one department at one time?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you are looking for, this should work:

```
SELECT 
    d.DepartmentId, 
    d.Name, 
    d.GroupName,
    SUM(eph.Rate * 40 * 52) as AnnualPay,
    Count(edh.EmployeeId) as EmployeeCount
from HumanResources.Department d 
JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory edh
ON edh.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
JOIN HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory eph
ON edh.EmployeeID = eph.EmployeeID
JOIN HumanResources.Employee e
ON e.EmployeeID = eph.EmployeeID
WHERE e.CurrentFlag = 'True' 
GROUP BY d.departmentID,d.Name,d.GroupName
HAVING AnnualPay > 500000
ORDER BY AnnualPay DESC;
```

Comment: As originally posted, this would not run due to the line `SUM(eph.Rate * 40 * 52 * Count(edh.EmployeeId))`. You can't nest aggregates like that. Also, it's not necessary. The source data relates to all employees, when you SUM their individual salaries, you don't then also need to multiply by how many employees there are.

Comment: I have just made a minro change to my code.  It's probably not the cause of the error, but if it does start working now, then please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT DepartmentId AS DepartmentId,
       DepartmentName AS DepartmentName,
       DepartmentGroup AS DepartmentGroup,
       SUM( expectedAnnualPay ) AS TotalExpectedAnnualPay,
       COUNT( DepartmentId ) AS EmployeeCount
(
    SELECT Department.DepartmentId AS DepartmentId,
           Name AS DepartmentName,
           GroupName AS DepartmentGroup
           Rate *
               40 *
               52 AS expectedAnnualPay,
           EmployeeID AS EmployeeID
    FROM HumanResources.Department HRDepartment
    JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory HREmployeeDepartmentHistory ON HREmployeeDepartmentHistory.DepartmentID = HRDepartment.DepartmentID
    JOIN HumanResources.Employee HREmployee ON HREmployee.EmployeeID = HREmployeeDepartmentHistory.EmployeeID
    JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory HREmployeeDepartmentHistory ON HREmployee.EmployeeID = HREmployeePayHistory.EmployeeID
    WHERE HREmployee.CurrentFlag = 'True'
) departmentEmployee
GROUP BY DepartmentId
HAVING TotalExpectedAnnualPay > 500000
ORDER BY TotalExpectedAnnualPay DESC;
```

You appear to be asking for a list of the total *expected* annual pay amount for each department where that value is greater than $500,000.00 on the assumption that all current employees within that Department will remain with that Department for one year at the current Rate and that no Employees will be added during that time.

I approached this problem by starting with the following query (which I gave the alias of `departmentEmployeeLevel`)...

```
SELECT Department.DepartmentId AS DepartmentId,
       Name AS DepartmentName,
       GroupName AS DepartmentGroup
       Rate *
           40 *
           52 AS expectedAnnualPay,
       EmployeeID AS EmployeeID
FROM HumanResources.Department HRDepartment
JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory HREmployeeDepartmentHistory ON HREmployeeDepartmentHistory.DepartmentID = HRDepartment.DepartmentID
JOIN HumanResources.Employee HREmployee ON HREmployee.EmployeeID = HREmployeeDepartmentHistory.EmployeeID
JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory HREmployeeDepartmentHistory ON HREmployee.EmployeeID = HREmployeePayHistory.EmployeeID
WHERE HREmployee.CurrentFlag = 'True'
```

This subquery returns the `DepartmentId`, Department `Name` and `GroupName` of each department along with the `EmployeeID` of each current Employee and their computed expected annual pay.

The main query uses the results of the subquery to aggregate / group together the results by each Department and to calculate for each Department the total of the expected annual pay and the count of employees.  It then uses `HAVING` to refine the list to only those departments whose expected annual pay cost is greater than $500,000.00 and sorts the remaining records by that field.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line number 12
Incorrect syntax near '('.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line number 14
Incorrect syntax near 'eph'.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed error message.  That does actually help.  I have updated my code.  Please try the modified code.

Comment: `select d.DepartmentID, d.Name, d.GroupName, sum(eph.Rate * 52 * 40) as TotalAnnualPay
from HumanResources.Department d, 
HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory eph,
HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory edh, HumanResources.Employee e
where d.DepartmentID = edh.DepartmentID 
and eph.EmployeeID = edh.EmployeeID
 and e.EmployeeID = eph.EmployeeID 
and e.CurrentFlag = 'True' 
group by d.departmentId, d.name, d.groupname
Having sum(eph.rate * 52 * 40) > 500000
Order by 4 desc;`

Comment: I came up with this piece of code and it did return a result that looks reasonable and correct but I can't know for sure, Please give me your opinion on it.

Comment: Typing up analysis now - please hold... :)

Comment: (1 / 3) Firstly, I do not like ultrashort aliases - in larger and more complex statements they can be easy to lose track of.  I have known this to be the cause of several bugs.

Secondly, this uses `CROSS JOIN`s refined by a `WHERE` statement rather than `INNER JOINS`.  An `INNER JOIN` (which is the type of jojn performed when you see just `JOIN`) is considered more efficient and (nowadays) better practice.

Comment: (2 / 3) Thirdly, it is protocol (and often more efficient) for your `JOIN`s to reflect your database design.  It would be better to join `EmployeePayHistory` to `Employee` rather than `EmployeeDepartmentHistory`.

Fourthly, as fields of `Department`, `Name` and `GroupName` are dependent on `DepartmentID`.  If you `GROUP BY` `departmentId` then you effectively can't group by the other two fields.  You should only specify a subgrouping if the field to be grouped upon is not dominated by the the field(s) higher in the grouping hierarchy.

Comment: (3 / 4) For example, in a situation similar to your you may wish to use `GROUP BY DepartmentId, EmployeeID` or `GROUP BY DepartmentID, Rate`.

Fifthly, the supplied code does not produce a count of Employees.

Sixthly (yes, it's a word), `ORDER BY 4 DESC` will work here.  Be careful when using this style that you change the value if you ever change order of fields it applies to.  Also, not all programmers approve of this one.  Be mindful of your likely audience.

Comment: (4 / 4) Finally, to aid in debugging try to get in the habit of fully capitalising semireserved words `SELECT`, `WHERE`, `AND`, `AS`, etc.  This helps differentiate them from names that you define (like table names, field names, etc.).

Comment: Explanation added.

Comment: Can't you remove the outer level query and use a `HAVING` clause on the total salary instead? Also, are you missing from `FROM`s?

Comment: I have finally researched the difference between `HAVING` and `WHERE`, and yes I can (and will).  Also, thank you for pointing out the missing 'FROM'.